# HTML page changes not showing in user's Chrome broswer

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser-cache, cache-control

I have some simple HTML pages that are updated about weekly.  I use Firefox myself, but my customer uses Chrome and he cannot see the revised content.  There are users all over the world so I do not want to have to tell them that they must do specific changes in their browser or to manually clear the cache.  I want for Chrome be able to pick up the revised HTML content that has been uploaded to the server.

I do version the files like this and change the version date for every change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?version=140821" media="screen" />
```

I also have the following, although I realize they may be obsolete, but may work for some browsers.

```
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
```

**What else can I do IN THE HTML CODE to get my customers able to see the changed content without having to refresh on each page?  What am I missing?**

(I realize they may have to refresh once after I fix my code.)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not move away from plain html and into a CMS?

Comment: I have used some CMS systems before, but the structure and style of the site does not really lend itself to using a CMS. Don't think I have not thought about this before. ;-)  I'm afraid there are too many tweaks needed after receiving text and images from the customer. Right now we do not have or need a database, so that would be something new for the site. The CMS I used to use (home grown in my company) did not have enough flexibility to support this site's design.  I'll consider it in the future.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: This could be better if you explained how it worked and what you are doing

Comment: Thank you, Ishita.  I have made these modifications to my pages.  I believe that the real problem is that the domain name is pointing to a different domain name that is actually hosted on the server.  There is other strange behavior with this setup.  For example, if on some page using the pointed url (sorry if I don't know the correct term), and then reload the page, it goes back to the home page.  I need to find a good host for this first domain.  Thanks for your help.